# Batch file - If folder is empty change caption

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will change title of command prompt window depending on the folder content. So if the folder is empty it should say **Empty** and if it's not then **Full**.

I've tried it with just one condition, but it won't work:

```
@echo on
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "C:\folder\*.*"') do (
    TITLE Empty
)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why not simply use [`if exist`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), like this: `if exist "C:\folder\*" (title Full) else (title Empty)`...

Comment: @aschipfl, with an empty existing directory `C:\folder`, `if exist "C:\folder\*"` will still be TRUE!

Comment: Yes, @Compo, so the target directory is not empty...

Comment: @aschipfl, I think you may have misunderstood what I wrote. Create a new directory, do not propagate it with any files, then try the code you suggested. You'll note that it will change the title to `Full`, not `Empty`!

Comment: Now I got it, @Compo, you're absolutely right -- thanks for the hint, and sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something along these lines, *(after modifying `C:\folder` as necessary)*.

This will check if there are any files:

```dos
@Dir /B/A-D "C:\folder">NUL 2>&1&&(Title Full)||Title No files
```

This will check if there are any files or directories:

```dos
@Dir /B/A "C:\folder">NUL 2>&1&&(Title Full)||Title Empty
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in golfing this into a single line?

Comment: Yes @zb226, because it is a single action and should easily fit on a single line of a standard cmd.exe window, _(with default 80 character width)_. The code works directly on the command line, as well as in a [tag:batch-file].

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend using `@ECHO OFF` instead of `@ECHO ON` which is redundant and it'll cause the a lot of useless output to be printed. The `\*.*` suffix for the `DIR` command is also implicitly given and thus unnecessary.

You're correctly using a `FOR` loop, but you'd need to at least set the title to `Empty` beforehand:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Empty
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B "C:\folder"') DO (
    TITLE Full
)
```

Unfortunately this will cause a noticeable flickering of the title when the directory is `Full`.

Better to store the directory state and set the title accordingly.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B "C:\folder"') DO (
    SET full=true
)
IF "%FULL%"=="true" (
    TITLE Full
) ELSE (
    TITLE Empty
)
```